# On generating set of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I am following Kurosh's Group Theory, in which, I am looking following result.

> Let $(G,+)$ be an abelian group, and $\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\}$ and $\{v_1,\ldots, v_l\}$ be elements of $G$ such that
>
> (I) $u_i$'s are linearly independent (i.e. integral combination of them is $0$ only if all coefficients are $0$);
>
> (II) Each $u_i$ is linearly dependent on $v_j$'s.
>
> Then $k\le l$. Moreover, we can omit $k$ members among $v_j$'s so that remaining $v$'s along with $u_1,\ldots, u_k$ form a system which is equivalent to $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_l$ (i.e. integral combination of this system is equal to integral combination of $v_1,\ldots, v_l$).

**Proof:** By induction on $k$. The Theorem is obvious for $k=0$. Assume it is true for $k-1$.

Thus, since $u_1,u_2, u_{k-1}$ are independent, so we can replace $k-1$ members in $v$'s (say without loss, $v_1,\ldots, v_{k-1}$) so that
$$
\{ u_1, \ldots, u_{k-1}, \,\, v_k, \ldots, v_l \} \,\,\,\, \mbox{ and } \,\,\,\, 
\{v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_l\} \hskip2cm (*)
$$
are equivalent, i.e. integral combinations of these sets generate same abelian subgroup of $G$.

Next, $u_k$ is dependent on second set in $(*)$, hence it is dependent on first set in $(*)$; thus
there are integers $a\neq 0$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_k$ such that
$$
au_k = (b_1u_1 + \ldots + b_{k-1}u_{k-1}) + (b_kv_k + \ldots + b_lv_l).
$$
It follows that $l\ge k$. [**HOW?**]

It could be very trivial question, but I did not get what contradiction comes if $l<k$; I don't get the author's assertion $l\ge k$. Especially, I don't understand how the induction step for $k-1$ is applied if $l<k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $l < k$ then the second part of your displayed sum $b_kv_k + \cdots +b_lv_l$ is empty, so we get $au_k = b_1u_1 + \cdots +b_{k-1}u_{k-1}$, contradicting the linear independence of $u_1,\ldots,u_k$.

Note that the inductive step tells you that $k-1 \le l$, and we are only replacing $k-1$ vectors in the replacement process, so there is not problem there.

Having said that, I am confused by the result itself, because if $G = {\mathbb Z}$, $k=l=1$, $u_1=1$ and $v_1=2$, then we don't delete any $v$'s, but the two sets do not generate the same subgroup.

Comment: I agree with you. But Kurosh's book does not contain the phrases "i.e. integral combination of them is $0$ only if all coefficients are $0$" and "i.e. integral combinations of these sets generate the same abelian subgroup of G". These words belong entirely to the author of the question.

Comment: @kabenyuk But presumably ``each $u_i$ is linearly dependent on $v_j$'s'' comes from the book? I am not familiar with that expression. It could mean each $u_i$ is a linear combination of the $v_i$'s, or it could mean that, for each $i$, the set $\{u_i,v_1,\ldots,v_l\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Unfortunately, the author of the question seems not to have understood
this point either.
Here is the definition from Kurosh's book:
An element $u\in G$ linearly dependent on the
system of elements $v_i\in G$, $1\leq i\leq s$ if there are integers
$\alpha\neq0$ and $\beta_i$ such that
$$
\alpha u=\beta_1v_1+\ldots+\beta_s v_s
$$
that is, the set $\{u,v_1,\ldots,v_s\}$ is linearly dependent.